# Socket.io events not firing once connected after previous failed attempt

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Here's the scenario, I have a client side application, served by PHP on a different server to the node.js + socket.io application. It can connect and receive broadcasts sent from the server. If the connection drops, the application falls back to polling a database (using `setInterval()`). It attempts to reconnect every 5 polls, and it can successfully reconnect and continue to receive messages.

My problem occurs when the user loads the page and the node server cannot be reached (I turned it off for testing), I then turn on the server and on the 5th poll, it successfully connects to the server, using `socket.socket.reconnect();`. However, whenever the server broadcasts messages, it doesn't fire the event. Note that this doesn't happen when testing on a phone (which falls back to a different socket method)

I have already seen the question found here [Reconnection in socket.io problem in `socket.on('message',function(){})`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960184/reconnection-in-socket-io-problem-in-socket-onmessage-function), however, the socket has not previously been connected so I don't think it could be the session?

EDIT: I changed the `socket.socket.reconnect()` to `socket.socket.connect()` and it fixed the problem. If someone could explain the reasons of why this works I'd like to know. I know its because the server isn't actually reconnecting, but would like more info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you possibly know the reason for this. server is not reconnecting. it is actually connecting. when you tell socket.io to reconnect it searches for the previous connection handle and thats where the problem arises.